# How to determine effective permissions and how granted for a local or domain account

Tags: sql-server, security

With SQL Server - if you have a local or domain user (including accounts like LOCAL SYSTEM) how can you determine

- What effective permissions they have on a database
- How those permissions are granted (e.g. which roles, any direct etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Server you can look for

```
exec sp_helpsrvrolemember sysadmin exec sp_helpsrvrolemember dbcreator
```

In the databases that you want

```
exec sp_helprolemember db_datareader
exec sp_helprolemember db_datawriter
exec sp_helprolemember db_ddladmin
exec sp_helprolemember db_owner
```

and all direct permissions

```
exec sp_helprotect null,null
```